How to merge dictionary of dataframes and make key values a column in merged dataframe
I have a dictionary of about 600 dataframes for connectome metrics for those 600 participants. I'm making a dummy dictionary though for conciseness. The dataframes all have 1 row. Ignore the fact that the actual meaning of "mean" as the column names are not what is of the row samples I give below, they're just the column names of all the dataframes I want to merge. Each of the keys are unique.
Two example dataframes would look like this:
Key = "Sonic"
Value_df = 

mean   median   stdev   min   max   count
1      3        7       9     22     11

Key = "Tails"
Value_df = 

mean   median   stdev   min   max   count
3      5        11      22    33     14


where...
{"Sonic":Dataframe, "Tails":Dataframe}
How do I merge the dictionary's dataframe and make the key values its own column in the final dataframe?
Subject   mean   median   stdev   min   max   count
Sonic     1      3        7       9     22     11
Tails     3      5        11      22    33     14

I've tried from_dict and I didn't have any luck.

You need to concat, then reset_index:
dic = {'Sonic': sonic_df, 'Tails': tails_df}

out = (pd.concat(dic, names=['Subject']).reset_index(0)
         .reset_index(drop=True) # optional
      )

Output:
  Subject  mean  median  stdev  min  max  count
0   Sonic     1       3      7    9   22     11
1   Tails     3       5     11   22   33     14

